# Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [response is not defined] after Apex Controller method referenced in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

End goal - create a lightning component with a button that calls an Apex Controller method.

The apex controller method is finally being called, but I don't know how to resolve this JS error that is thrown after the Apex method finishes.

Cmp where the controller is defined in line 1:

```html
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="updateUsingLightningCheckboxController">
    <ui:button label="Activate" press="{!c.onActivate}" aura:id="Activate"/>
</aura:component>
```

JS Controller where the Apex Controller method is called in line 4 successfully:

```js
    ({
    onActivate: function(cmp, evt, helper){
        alert("button clicked");
        var action = cmp.get("c.startScheduler");
        alert("cmp gotten?");
        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                alert("From server:" + response.getReturnValue());
            }//if
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }})
```

Trimmed Apex Controller, where the method works just fine for a VF button but throws the exception for the above lightning component:

```java
public with sharing class updateUsingLightningCheckboxController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String startScheduler(){
        system.debug('scheduler method started');
        String responseMessage='The app is already scheduled for hourly runs.  Click Deactivate in order to stop the app from updating the custom field: "Using Lightning?"';
        List<CronTrigger> ct=[SELECT Id, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronExpression =: updateUsingLightningCheckboxUtils.cronJobSchedule];
        if (ct.size()==0){
            updateUsingLightningCheckboxScheduler.start(); 
            } else {
        }//if
        return responseMessage;
    }//startScheduler
}//Apex Controller
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have used data as the callback variable name and hence client side code is failing .

Use data.getState() and data.getReturnvalue() in your code.

Comment: data.getReturnValue() not data.getResponse()

Comment: Ah I see .typo sir